# setting div background image only works on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I set a div background with a `setPic()` function. I use a `changePic()` function to update the picture

**html**

```
div.profileimg(id="img", ng-style="imagePath")
```

**angular/js**

```
function setPic() {
    console.log("in set pic")
    var url = '/api/image?spotId=' + $window.sessionStorage.getItem("currentGarage")
    $http.get(url).then(
        function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("Success get image")
            $scope.imagePath = {};
            $scope.imagePath = {
                background: 'url(' + url + ')'
            };
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("fail get image")
        });

}


changePic = function(fd) {
    url = "/api/spot/pic/post?spotId=" + $window.sessionStorage.getItem("currentGarage");
    $http.post(url, fd, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).then(
        function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("Success post image")
            setPic();
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("fail post image")
        });
};
```

The `setPic()` function is called once at the beginning of the controller (works), and then once inside the success clause of the `changePic()` function. Why does calling `setPic()` after page load not work?

One more question. Notice how I define the functions differently. One is `function name()` and the other is `name = function()`. `setPic()` is called from the controller and not the dom. If I change the form of this function my site does not build and I see `{{}}` in my fields. `changePic()` is registered in the `onclick` of a button and if I change the form of that function, the click does not register. Seriously mind-blowing craziness here. Should I go take a javascript/angular course before attempting to code anymore?

Comment: in ``setPic`` you are getting img from ``$http`` by ``url`` and then you put the same ``url`` in your ``background`` property :O is there a reason for that? maybe you want get brand new ``url`` from ``/api/image?spotId`` response and put this new url in your background?

Comment: in controller functions will work, but outside of it - it is outside of angular dependency injection and it won't work of course. if you set something on controller start it will work after everything is loaded. so why you want this outside? i don't know what you want to achieve

Comment: use ng-click instead of onclick and put your functions inside scope like ``$scope.setPic=function(){...}```